# EF maps SQL float to decimal

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I changed a field in my SQL table from decimal to float and selected "Update model from database" in the designer, but the entity still has the field as a decimal, and so I get a complier error "member mapping is not valid"

Why would the update from DB not function correctly? I was expecting the entity to regenerate with a float type.

Thanks

UPDATE: actually I see it should map to double. But I cannot get it to change from decimal when updating.  I guess I shouldn't do it manually as it will be overwritten again later with decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the property from your POCO class and `"Update model from database"` again.

Comment: Actually what I did was go to the Mapping Details window, then the properties of the specific mapping and changed it to Double manually. Regenerated and it didn't revert to Decimal. But I guess your suggestion would have worked too. Thanks

Comment: Have in mind that EF is not 100% correct always and that is quite normal. So always is handy to dip your hands into the code, its not bad.Actually its kind of required. If you find the answer useful you could mark it.